# How to generate dynamic variable inside for loop and sum values to assign the dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create dynamic variable and sum values again to assign the dynamic variable?

For Example,

```
var incomeCr = 0, incomeDr = 0;

for (var j = 1; j <= noOfMonths; j++) 
{
    if(response[i]["AmountType" + j] == "Cr")
    {
        if(response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] < 0)
        {
           response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] = -1 * response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j];
        }
        incomeCr += parseFloat(response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j]);
    }
    else if (response[i]["AmountType" + j] == "Dr")
    {
        if (response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] < 0)
        {
            response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] = -1 * response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j];
        }
        incomeDr += parseFloat(response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j]);
    }
}
```

Here how to create dynamic variable incomeCr1, incomeCr2... and incomeDr1, incomeDr2... and sum the values again assign values to dynamic variable.

Comment: Please give us some more explaination of what you want to achieve

Comment: why do you need `incomeCr1`,`incomeCr2`,... variables??

Comment: here sum the ClosingBalanceWithType value and assign to sum dynamic variable based on AmountType cr and dr separately

Comment: calculate income values (i.e) totalincome1 = incomeCr1-incomeDr1, totalincome2=incomeCr2-incomeDr2.. etc., So how to create dynamically incomrCr1, 2,3.. and incomeDr1, 2,3.... and finally get totalincome1, 2,3....

Answer (score 0):

You can not create dynamic variables like that. Instead use an array:

```
var incomeCr = [];
//incomeCr[1], incomeCr[2],...
incomeCr[1] = "txt";
incomeCr[2] = "txt2";
```

Comment: k. Suppose inside for loop incomeCr[1]=0, incomeCr[1]=55, incomeCr[1]=10..... and i want output incomeCr[1]=65. Same as incomeCr[2], incomeCr[3].. etc.,

Answer (score 0):

```
var incomeCr = 0, incomeDr = 0, expenseCr = 0, expenseDr = 0, iIncomeCr = {}, eExpenseCr = {}, iIncomeDr = {}, eExpenseDr = {}, cr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            // Sum Primary Group Income on each Month
            if (response[i].Type == "Ledger" && response[i].PrimaryGroup == "Incomes") {
                for (var j = 1; j <= noOfMonths; j++) {
                    if (response[i]["AmountType" + j] == "Cr") {
                        if (response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] < 0) {
                            response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] = -1 * response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j];
                        }
                        iIncomeCr["incomeCr" + j] = (iIncomeCr["incomeCr" + j] ? iIncomeCr["incomeCr" + j] : 0) + parseFloat(response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j]);
                        iIncomeDr["incomeDr" + j] = iIncomeDr["incomeDr" + j] ? iIncomeDr["incomeDr" + j] : 0;
                    } else if (response[i]["AmountType" + j] == "Dr") {
                        if (response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] < 0) {
                            response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j] = -1 * response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j];
                        }
                        iIncomeDr["incomeDr" + j] = (iIncomeDr["incomeDr" + j] ? iIncomeDr["incomeDr" + j] : 0) + parseFloat(response[i]["ClosingBalanceWithType" + j]);
                        iIncomeCr["incomeCr" + j] = iIncomeCr["incomeCr" + j] ? iIncomeCr["incomeCr" + j] : 0;
                    }
                }
            }
```